# Validate if the input contains more than one char from a-Z using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate if the input contains more than one char from a-Z using RegEx.

It can contain any number of characters, spaces but may/may not contain one letter from a-Z.

If it contains it won´t be more than one.

```
public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String []args){

     String s  = "333444434";//None / Only 1
     //String s  = "A b c";//More than 1
     //String s  = "111 1Aa1 1111";//More than 1
     //String s  = "98X8 8A+----!";//More than 1
     //String s  = "98A88a+----!";//More than 1
     //String s  = "c+->18888882";//None / Only 1
     //String s  = "1c+-**>18888882";//None / Only 1

     if(s.matches("([a-zA-Z]){0,1}")){
        System.out.println("None / Only 1");
     }else{
        System.out.println("More than 1");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: `s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]","").length()<=1`

Comment: i don't see this comment, @SanketMakani i already post an answer similar and i get down-vote, maybe because they thought i take it from your comment, i suggest to post it like an answer

Comment: @YCF_L, I don't think so otherwise they would have upvoted the comment. Maybe they think that this will consume memory which is don't requried.

Comment: @SanketMakani, Thanks its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a matcher that search for a `[a-zA-Z]` regex and count them:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]")
                         .matcher(s);
int counter = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
  counter++;
}
if (counter <= 1) {
  System.out.println("None / Only 1");
} else {
  System.out.println("More than 1");
}
```